# Code implementation Singleton Design Pattern: Bill Pugh on a Retrofit object

Tags: android, android-studio, singleton, retrofit2

I have been trying to implement the Bill Pugh Singleton Design Pattern using a private static class to return the singleton retrofit instance. SO far I have been able to come up with the following code. Can someone help me review this code and confirm if this is a proper implementation of the singleton design pattern suggested by Mr. Bill Pugh Himself or suggest me a proper way of implementing this.

```
public class SingletonRetrofit {

    private SingletonRetrofit(){}

    private static class SingletonRetrofitHelper {

        private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
        private static Retrofit retrofit;

        private static Retrofit makeRetrofit() {

            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://ci.draftserver.com/hornsbyapp/webservice/")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

            return retrofit;

        }
    }

    public static Retrofit getInstance() {
        return SingletonRetrofitHelper.makeRetrofit();
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is working code then Code Review SE is [down the hall](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JohnBollinger First door on your right. ;)

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yup the code is working fine and thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

USE this one:

```
public class Apiclient {

    private static final String BASE_URL ="URL";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {

        if (retrofit == null) {

          OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient2 = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
          httpClient2.addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {

            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
                builder.addHeader("site_id","1");
                return chain.proceed(builder.build());
            }
          });
          OkHttpClient client = httpClient2.build();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
         }
         return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Comment: I donot believe this is Bill Pugh Implementation. so

Comment: this provides singleton object of retrofit

Comment: i know this provides the singleton object but this is a Lazy Implementation of Singleton. 
http://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples
Have a read